# Python 3D Rendering

Tags: python, 3d, rendering

I want to render a grid plane in 3d with integer coordinate in given size (<= 50 * 50) using Python. On the grid, there are a multiple of cube at given points. Could you tell me which module and tool that I should use?

I try Matplotlib but when it render a huge model, it will lag and slow. I try Ursina too, but it cant render my grid if grid's too large (>= 20 * 20).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.